Ruby on Rails - CarrierWave image versions are not being created
I'm running this code: https://github.com/Retrospring/retrospring. When I upload a profile image, the URL of the image is /users/profile_pictures/112/951/283/757/351/898/medium/io.png. However, that path does not exist in the public/ directory in the cloned retrospring repo, but public/users/profile_pictures/112/951/283/757/351/898/original/io.png does exist. I assume it has something to do with CarrierWave, as configured in app/uploaders/profile_picture_uploader.rb:
class ProfilePictureUploader < BaseUploader
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/#{[version_name || args.first, 'no_avatar.png'].compact.join('/')}"
  end

  version :large do
    process resize_to_fit: [500, 500]
  end
  version :medium do
    process resize_to_fit: [256, 256]
  end
  version :small do
    process resize_to_fit: [80, 80]
  end
end

BaseUploader subclasses CarrierWave::Uploader::Base:
class BaseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Compatibility::Paperclip
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  storage :fog

  # Store original size
  version :original

  process :remove_animation
  process :cropping

  def content_type_whitelist = %w[image/jpeg image/gif image/png]

  def store_dir = "/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"

  def size_range = (1.byte)..(5.megabytes)

  def paperclip_path
    return "/users/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension" if APP_CONFIG["fog"].blank?

    "users/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension"
  end

  def cropping
    x = model.public_send("#{mounted_as}_x")
    y = model.public_send("#{mounted_as}_y")
    w = model.public_send("#{mounted_as}_w")
    h = model.public_send("#{mounted_as}_h")

    manipulate! do |image|
      image.crop "#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
    end
  end

  def remove_animation
    return unless content_type == "image/gif"

    manipulate!(&:collapse!)
  end
end

How can I fix this?
